# Google Spreadsheet Import unique values

Tags: google-sheets

need your help with google spreadsheet.

Here is example of data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JGLQ0UoafpFkoDm7hstVnZPK96sf3g9sSuGxBmruG3Y/edit?usp=sharing

I need to import to another sheet data from this table based on data in column E.
 So if there is some item in column E more than once, i need to import only one example (row) of it (any).

I tried to use formula Unique(), but it doesn't work as column D is always Unique, so in this case all data is imported anyway.

In the Sheet 2, I have also tried to import first of all data form column E, and than based on it to import rest of information with the help of Sumproduct(). I tried to use Filter() but its has error about mismatched range sizes.

Would really appreciate your help,
Feel free to modify example sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to return the first row containing the unique value in column E then this formula should work in cell H2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2:G,{E:E,A:D},{2,3,4,5},0)))`

I added it to a 'Copy of Sheet2' tab in your example sheet